# Laravel how to make that id would not be shown through inspect

Tags: laravel

I have form like this

```
<form action="{{ url('/reviews/delete', ['id' => $review->id]) }}"method="POST">
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<a class="delete right-button"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
</form>
```

When I use inspect I see the id and if I change it I can delete different record depends on which id I fill into inspection. How to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the record by doing so?

Comment: @linktoahref yeah I was able to delete different record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in the controller like so

`abort_if($user->id !== $review->user_id, 404)`

personally I like using policies https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#writing-policies

```
$this->authorize('delete', $review);
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that HTML already renders the form and when you `submit` it, request reads the URL inside the action and goes there, so there is no 'real' answer on how to prevent it, but you can put some validation in the [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation).

If you want to go further you can create [Model Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#writing-policies) and check if the review belongs to the user which is trying to remove it, or some other kind of validation.